# BC30452: Issue using '=' Operator with Integer Variable & Array of Integers - VB Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio, vbscript, crystal-reports

I'm new to Visual Basic having no prior experience, other than using office macros (made by others and not myself) and crash coursing myself over the past 1-2 days, so pardon the basic nature of my question.

I've come across a task whereby I need to use VB in CrystalReports to make simple formulas to decide what information to populate the formula containing field. I currently don't have access to CrystalReports on my system so I'm testing the loops/decisions as VBScripts to see if they'll work.

I have 2 working loops so far, but wanted a third to give the user more option to which they want to use.

The loop below is the one I'm having an issue with:

```
    Dim userinput1 As Integer = Nothing
    Dim arrayset1 = New Integer() {1, 2, 3, 4}
    Dim arrayset2 = New Integer() {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    Dim arrayset3 = New Integer() {10, 11, 12, 13}
    Dim arrayother = New Integer() {14} 'this is just to keep with array formatting, no real reason for the 1 value array other than that

    Console.WriteLine("Enter Value:") 
    userinput1 = Console.ReadLine() 
    Console.WriteLine("Value Entered = " & userinput1) 
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.ReadLine()

    If userinput1 = arrayset1 Then 
        Console.WriteLine(userinput1 & "_SUFFIX1")
    ElseIf userinput1 = arrayset2 Then
        Console.WriteLine(userinput1 & "_SUFFIX2")
    ElseIf userinput1 = arrayset3 Then
        Console.WriteLine(userinput1 & "_SUFFIX3")
    ElseIf userinput1 = arrayother Then
        Console.WriteLine(userinput1 & "_SUFFIX4")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine(userinput1)
    End If
```

Im writing and testing this in Visual Studio 2017 Community, and when I run the code I receive the error "BC30452 Operator '=' is not defined for types 'Integer' and 'Integer()'."

To be completely honest I'm not sure why I'm receiving this, and what exactly the difference between "Integer" and "Integer ()" is that's preventing them from being used with the '=' operator.

I have been trying to make it work, but most of my attempts lack useful direction due to lack of knowledge in VB (and not knowing relevant search terms to my issue.)

I had another 'version' of this loop where instead of using arrays I compared userinput1 to its value directly using...

```
if userinput1 = 1 Or userinput 1 =2 Or userinput1 = 3 Or userinput1 = 4 Then
    Console.WriteLine(userinput1 & "_SUFFIX1")
etc etc
.......
```

..and I had no problem running that.

With only 14 variable values *at this point in time* there isn't much issue with using "Or" like that, but there's a chance of the amount of variables increasing, and I would in that case like to keep this clean. I have another loop using "SelectCase" that's also clean(er), so failing this I still have that loop.

My question basically is, in what way am I incorrectly using arrays that's causing me issues? or if there is an error in how i've formatted my code, what is it?

Any other suggestions of how I may go about this other than what I've outlined above are welcome.

Thanks in advance,
LMacs.

P.S just to note there'll be no "Console.WriteLine" and such in the code being entered to CrystalReports, there will also be no user input. The write functions and inputs will be populated by database references.

Comment: `Integer()` is an array of integers rather than a single integer, so they cannot be directly compared.  If you want to see if the array _contains_ a specific integer, then you could use the Array's `Contains` or `IndexOf` method.

Comment: I had no idea they existed.

So I could use something like: 

    'If arrayset1.Contains(userinput1) Then' 
        'Console.WriteLine(userinput1 & "_SUFFIX1")'
?

Comment: Yes.  I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Integer()` is an array of integers, whereas `Integer` is just a single integer.  The error message is saying that you can't use the `=` operator to test if an array of integers is equal to a single integer.  The language doesn't know how to do that.  How would the language know what you mean?  Do you want to see if the array only contains a single integer which is the same value as the other integer?  Or do you want check if the array contains a specific value in its list of integers?  You need to be more exact about your intentions.

Based on your example, I assume that you want to see if the array contains the entered integer.  To do that, you can use the `Contains` method of the array:

```
If arrayset1.Contains(userinput1) Then 
    ' ...
```

However, `Contains` is actually an extension method provided by LINQ, so in order to use it, you need to import the `System.Linq` namespace.  If you don't want to (or can't) use LINQ, then you can use the `Array.IndexOf` method instead:

```
If Array.IndexOf(arrayset1, userinput1) >= 0 Then
    ' ...
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, this should work perfectly, and you assumed correct thats what I was attempting to do, sorry if I wasn't clear! And thats for the IndexOf example, that'll be the one i'll most likely have to use (I dont think i'll be able to use System.Linq in CrystalReports). Thank you!